# Why does readBoolean block but readObject doesn't?

Tags: java, stream

I have the following method in my client:

```
  public boolean save() {
    this.ostream.writeObject(Command.SAVE); // write to socket
    return this.istream.readBoolean();
  }
```

In my server:

```
    Object o = this.istream.readObject();
    if (o == Command.SAVE) {
      boolean isSaved = save(); // save to database
      this.ostream.writeBoolean(isSaved);
    }
```

If I use `readBoolean` and `writeBoolean`, the `readBoolean` method in the client blocks, but if I use `readObject` and `writeObject` instead, my application works fine. Is there a reason why the `readBoolean` method would block?

Comment: I think blocking is not the right word. Both are blocking. Question is why does one not return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Its more like comment but code example would be hard to read so I posted it as an answer... Hope it wont bother anyone*)

You sure about that? I've just tested it by this code

```
ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("d:/objects.obj"));
System.out.println("writeObject(true)");
out.writeObject(true);
System.out.println("writeBoolean(true)");
out.writeBoolean(true);
System.out.println("writeBoolean(true)");
out.writeBoolean(true);
out.close();//or flush
System.out.println("------------------");

ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("d:/objects.obj"));
System.out.println("readObject="+in.readObject());
System.out.println("readBoolean="+in.readBoolean());
System.out.println("readObject="+in.readObject());//<- readObject stored by writeBoolean
```

and it seams to work fine. Only problems I had was when I tried to `readObject` stored with `writeBoolean` or vice versa `readBoolean` stored with `writeObject`.

Maybe you just need to flush output stream.